# angular-cli : get list of third-party software bundled

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli

Any idea how to get list of all ThirdParty software being bundled via angular-cli.
Currently I'm using ng build prod, which do generate 3rdPartyLicense.txt (using license-webpack plugin)

Which also lists webpack and some other licenses. But is there any tool/plugin which can list what all third software bundled via angular-cli.
Also would need list of indirect dependencies. e.g. say webpack shown in dependency but what about dependencies of webpack.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can show all your dependencies by

```
npm ls --depth=0 --json --parseable
```

or programmatically (from some Node.js driven script)

```
JSON.parse(require('child_process').execSync('npm ls --depth=0 --json --parseable')).dependencies
```

Feel free to change (or remove?) `--depth=0` in order to get the dependencies tree higher / smaller.

If you need to use it in your angular frontend just import the output json into the app.

Problem is that as long as the list of dependencies is normally superhuge you would need to distinguish between the dependencies you need vs dependencies you don't need; however this is not a subject of this question.

The problem of your statement

> what all third software bundled via angular-cli

is that you / me / tool don't know what and how exactly and at which moment is used by angular-cli. So all you can is having **all** your dependencies.